# Gwibber only launches sometimes

Tags: gwibber

I face this problem where Gwibber only launches sporadically. Sometimes when I click it to launch, it launches and then other times it doesn't. I can't seem to figure out what is preventing it from launching and what sort of information I need to collect, also where to collect it from to make a bug report.

I have killed the gwibber-service processes in the System Monitor "*it loads three processes called gwibber-service, is this normal*" several times and tried to launch Gwibber again, but this doesn't seem to work. The process just called gwibber starts, then the three gwibber-service processes start, then the gwibbber process ends and the three gwibber-service processes remain but the application is still not launching.

Generally, I want to know are other people facing the same problem. If someone can give me some guidance on how to triage this problem and get the information need to make a bug report I would be grateful.

The upside to this though is at least when it is not launching it is preventing me from wasting endless hours reading my streams on Identi.ca and Twitter, so it is a bit [Workrave](http://www.workrave.org/) for microblogging. In which case maybe I shouldn't fix this problem :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try running gwibber from the command-line. You can do that by starting a terminal (`Menu > Accessories > Terminal`) and then typing `gwibber` and hitting enter. If it's crashing on startup, it'll probably tell you why.

If Gwibber isn't working for you, you can always try [Tweetdeck](http://support.tweetdeck.com/entries/181425-how-to-install-air-tweetdeck-in-linux-ubuntu-variants). It's closed source, but functional.

Comment: I'll give that a go when the problem next occures and come back here with the results. I wouldn't go near Tweetdeck sorry, I don't like Adobe AIR, I don't like closed source and Tweetdeck is only interested in Twitter. I want a client that can working with Identi.ca, Status.net, Twitter, Buzz etc... thanks for the suggestion though.